# while compiling app am getting the error like this

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors, xcode4.2

This is the error log, which I got

```
Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMTPExample.app/SMTPExample normal i386
    cd /Users/apple/Desktop/SMTPExample
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/xcode4/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/apple/Desktop/SMTPExample -filelist /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Intermediates/SMTPExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMTPExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/SMTPExample.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework DropboxSDK -o /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMTPExample.app/SMTPExample

ld: duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize in /Users/apple/Desktop/SMTPExample/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK and /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMTPExample-dkhosyetbsajvtcdyyalnckswjgd/Build/Intermediates/SMTPExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMTPExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/Base64Transcoder.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: check out for duplicate variables in every .m files there may be some variable which you have declared in different .m file with same name

Comment: _EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize symbol used in multiple class...this is the main reason for occuring this type of error...

Answer (score 1):

This is a linker error (the "ld" in the output indicates this, because the output error has been generated by the [GNU linker program](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld)).

What has happened is that two identical declarations have been compiled separately from two separate source code files. One of these source files might be named `Base64Transcoder.m` or `Base64Transcoder.cpp` (as the compiled file that's caused the problem is `Base64Transcoder.o`). The declaration in question is `_EstimateBas64EncodingDataSize`. This symbol is being declared multiple times within different source code files, and then the linker is throwing an error because the two compiled source code files are different. You need to have a look through the entire source code that's being compiled and resolve the conflict.

Hope this helps and makes sense, I've always found linker issues difficult to understand and deal with. I'd really strongly suggest reading about the linker stages of program compilation for C/C++/Objective-C code ([this](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html) is a very good guide). Then you should be able to better understand what's going on under the hood! :)